# What is the appropriate DS for the following representation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have ten variables with the value `false` in `getInitialState`. Is there a better way to create the structure below rather than just listing them 10 times in a row?

```
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
     number: 1,
     visible1: false,
     visible2: false,
     visible3: false,
     visible4: false,
     visible5: false,
     visible6: false,
     visible7: false,
     visible8: false,
     visible9: false,
     visible10: false,
     image1: "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png",
     image2: "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png",
     image3: "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png",
     image4: "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png",
     image5: "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png",
     image6: "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png",
     image7: "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png",
     image8: "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png",
     image9: "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png",
     image10: "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png"
    }
  },
```

Note that **I cannot change the structure**, I'm just asking if there's a simpler way to create it (e.g., less repetition, fewer lines).

The images do all start out with the same path (it's a default, they'll get updated by the user).

Comment: Those are the default images, but the images will be replaced once the users starts clicking the div's, on which camera will be called and the those images will be replaced by ten camera images.

Comment: If you hover the downvote button, it gives the reasons for downvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to produce the `visibleX` and `imageX` properties:

```
getInitialState: function(){
    var rv = {
        number: 1
    };
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        rv["visible" + i] = false;
        rv["image" + i] = "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png";
    }
    return rv;
},
```

That produces exactly the same structure.

In JavaScript, you can access properties either with dot notation and a property name *literal* (`obj.foo`), or with brackets notation and a property name *string* (or `Symbol`, but that's not relevant here). So in the above, we use the brackets notation to create the 10 `visibleX` and `imageX` properties on the object.

---

You've said you can't change the structure, which is unfortunate as an array of objects would almost certainly be a better solution:

```
getInitialState: function(){
    var rv = {
        number: 1,
        images: []
    };
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        rv.images.push({
            visible: false,
            url: "https://www.bignerdranch.com/img/blog/2014/07/Button-2.png"
        });
    }
    return rv;
},
```